# Django: Change timezone while setting up server

Tags: python, django

I was setting up Django server on my system. Following steps from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/).

It says

> While you’re editing mysite/settings.py, set TIME_ZONE to your time zone.

I tried to change my `TIME_ZONE` like following :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'IST'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True`
```

I get the following error :
>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 123, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)  
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: IST
```

How can I set my `TIME_ZONE` to `IST`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

Or the one that is right for you. The format is "Continent/City"

Check the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Hope this helps